# For any odd prime $p≥5$, $(-3/p) = 1$ if $p ≡ 1,-5\pmod{12}$ and $(-3/p) = -1$ if $p ≡ -1,5 \pmod{12}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

For any odd prime $p≥5$, $(-3/p) = 1$ if $p ≡ 1,-5\pmod{12}$ and $(-3/p) = -1$ if $p ≡ -1,5 \pmod{12}$.

My solution so far: if $p ≡ 1\pmod{4}$ then $(-3/p) = 1$ exactly when $p ≡ ±1\pmod{12}$ when $p ≡ 1\pmod{12}$.

And if $p ≡ -1\pmod{4}$ then $(-3/p) = 1$ exactly when $p ≡ ±5\pmod{12}$ whence
$p ≡ -5\pmod{12}$. So $(-3/p) = 1$ exactly when $p ≡ 1\pmod{12}$ or $p ≡ -5\pmod{12}$.

I'm not very confident in my work. Is this correct and if it's not, how do you solve this problem?

Comment: you could say $\left(\dfrac{-3}p\right)=1$ if $p\equiv1\bmod3$ and $=-1$ if $p\equiv-1\bmod3$

Comment: How does that help? Im just confused on the general direction of how this proof is supposed to progress

Comment: If $p\equiv1\bmod4$ then $(-3/p)=(3/p)$ (since $(-1/p)=1$) and $(3/p)=(p/3)$ and $(p/3)$ is $1$ if $p\equiv1\bmod3$, $-1$ if $p\equiv2\bmod3$. Modifications apply for $p\equiv-1\bmod4$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense but how does that connect back to mod12?

Comment: If you know $p\equiv1\bmod4$, and you know $p\equiv1\bmod3$, wildcat, what can you say about $p\bmod{12}$? Do you not know how to convert information about mod 3 and mod 4 to information about mod 12? If not, read up on the Chinese Remainder Theorem – you'll be glad you did.

Comment: Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: So, wildcat, do you understand?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Super late response but yes thank you that helped a lot